# Calling vector of threads from destructor

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor, stdthread, move-constructor

Why can't I call my vector of threads from the destructor? Is there some rule for using destructors?

```
void p ()
{
    std::cout << "thread running " << std::endl;
}

class VecThreads // Error: In instantiation of member function 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::thread, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::thread> >::vector' requested here
{
public:
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    VecThreads() {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(p));
    }
    ~VecThreads()
    {
        threads[0].join();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    VecThreads h = VecThreads();
    //h.threads[0].join();  // delete deconstructor and use this works fine
  return 0;
}
```

The error I get:

> Calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::thread'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
VecThreads h = VecThreads();
```

`VecThreads` has no move constructor, its generation is disabled (i.e., *not declared*) because it has a *user-defined destructor*. Therefore, the statement above calls `VecThreads`'s copy constructor.

`VecThreads` contains a data member of type `std::vector<std::thread>` – which isn't copyable since an `std::thread` object is not copyable. Even though an `std::vector<std::thread>` is not copyable, it is movable, so a move constructor would, in principle, do the trick. You can explicitly enable the generation of the move constructor by adding the following inside `VecThreads`'s definition:

```
VecThreads(VecThreads&&) = default;
```

Your original code does compile since C++17 without modification thanks to *mandatory copy elision*.